# How to loop through jQuery .next function none -top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically loop through and scroll each element from a group of elements to the top of the page with jQuery `.next` function. However, the function scrolls just the first element, stops and doesn't loop though.

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var $next = $('.per-account:first').next('.per-account');
    var $first = $('.per-account:first');
    if ($next.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $next.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $first.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, 3000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: red;"> </div>

<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: blue;"> </div>

<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: orange;"> </div>

<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: green;"> </div>
```

the first element and stops. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

My code looks like below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always getting the next element after `:first`, which means it's always the second element, not looping.

Add a class to the current element, and then get the next element after that.

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var $current = $('.per-account.current')
    var $next = $current.next('.per-account');
    if (!$next.length) { // wrap around to the beginning
      $next = $('.per-account:first');
    }
    $current.removeClass('current');
    $next.addClass('current');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $next.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }, 3000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="per-account current" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: red;"> </div>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: blue;"> </div>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: orange;"> </div>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: green;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will make it work. You were starting from the **:first** at each interval.

```js
$(function() {

  function runScroll(){

    let $current = $('.per-account:first');
    const id = setInterval(runInterval, 1000);
    function runInterval(){
      if ( $current.next('.per-account').length ){
        $current = $current.next('.per-account');
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $current.offset().top
        }, 500);
      } else {
        clearInterval(id);
      }
    }

  }
  
  runScroll(); // Re-run to scroll again

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: red;"> </div>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: blue;"> </div>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: orange;"> </div>
<div class="per-account" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; background: green;"> </div>
```

Comment: Good lesson for me. How do I get it to start again when it gets to the end? Thank you so much.

Comment: You just wrap the code in a function and call it again. @VivianOnuagu